# October CMS, How to change date format in template?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I'm use code: `{{operation.updated_at->format('d.m.Y H:i')}}` , but this not working.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: which format you want and show which is the exact date

Comment: @Alfabravo, http://prntscr.com/hsi9zc

Comment: @kunal , format = d.m.Y H:i , date string = 2017-12-26 19:12:06

Comment: You should post things in an usable format (e.g. not screenshots). Also, you should add all the relevant information in the question (edit it) not in the comments. Glad you found an useful answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to add this in your `operation` model :

```
public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($date)
  {
      return Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)->format('d.m.Y H:i');
  }
```

Every time you use these properties from your model to show a date these will be presented differently.

```
$operation= Operation::find(1);
echo $operation->updated_at; // d.m.Y H:i will be displayed
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I need

Answer (score 1):

if understand your problem...May be you are looking for this:-

```
{{date('d.m.Y H:i',strtotime(operation.updated_at))}}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
operation.updated_at.format('d.m.Y H:i')
```

because `updated_at` is a Carbon Object